# How to have client-uploaded files stored on client-side, using Bootstrap form and Express server code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload, client-side

Basically, the user uploads a file, that file is stored on the user-side somewhere (I think this is what PHP does, is it not?), and the upload form that I'm using is a Bootstrap HTML form. I'm coding my server stuff with Express. I'm not sure where to start with this, so I'm not really not sure how to do some research on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one (simplest I found so far): https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload

There are examples too.

For more advanced, you can check this one as well: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

Comment: What makes multer more advanced?

Comment: Good question. I think it supports more options. I'm currently using only multer though. express-fileupload will just give you the ideas how it should be handled.